# The output shows NaN but ,I need the sum of the array

Tags: javascript

1.This code shows NaN
2.I changed subaray[1] to the number but shows NaN
3. please help to solve this

```js
let products = [
  'Underpants:6.99',
  'Socks:5.99',
  'T-shirt:14.99',
  'Trousers:31.99',
  'Shoes:23.99' ];
  
  
for(let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

    let subArray = products[i].split(':');

    let name = subArray[0];

    let price = Number(subArray[1]);

    let total;

    total += price;

    console.log(total) //total shows NaN

  }
```

Comment: Initialize `let total = 0;`, and pull it before the loop.

Comment: In modern JS you hardly ever use an index-based for-loop. I haven't done a single such loop in years of professional Javascript development.

Comment: sir, what process occur in this step: total += price; how the array sumed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move the total out of the loop, you're creating a new total variable every time your loop iterate. You should also assign a number to the total, so you don't sum a undefined with a number.

```js
let products = [
  'Underpants:6.99',
  'Socks:5.99',
  'T-shirt:14.99',
  'Trousers:31.99',
  'Shoes:23.99' ];
 
let total = 0;
  
for(let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

    let subArray = products[i].split(':');

    let name = subArray[0];

    let price = Number(subArray[1]);

    total += price;

    console.log(total) //total shows NaN

  }
```

Comment: sir, what process occur in this step:  total += price; how the array sumed

Comment: Your are spliting a string "shoes:23.99" by the ":", so you have now a new array of 2 indexes, where the second is "23.99". When you call the method Number('23.99'), you're transforming the string into a number, them you're making the sum between this number and the current total. Every iterate you take the array index and sum with the total. So "totalt += price" is equivalent to "total = total + price"

Answer (score 1):

typicaly use case for [array reduce() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let products = 
  [ 'Underpants:6.99'
  , 'Socks:5.99'
  , 'T-shirt:14.99'
  , 'Trousers:31.99'
  , 'Shoes:23.99'
  ] 
  
let total = products.reduce((a,c)=> a +Number(c.split(':')[1]), 0).toFixed(2)
  
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Fixing JS floating point math problems is not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize let total = 0;

```js
let products = [
  'Underpants:6.99',
  'Socks:5.99',
  'T-shirt:14.99',
  'Trousers:31.99',
  'Shoes:23.99' ];

let total = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    let subArray = products[i].split(':');
    let name = subArray[0];
    let price = Number(subArray[1]); 
    total += price;
    console.log(total) //total shows NaN
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the array methods available for such tasks, in this case [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let products = ['Underpants:6.99', 'Socks:5.99', 'T-shirt:14.99', 'Trousers:31.99', 'Shoes:23.99'];

let total = products.reduce((acc, val) => acc + Number(val.split(':')[1]), 0);

console.log(total);
```

`Array.prototype.reduce`, as the name says, is the right function whenever you need to reduce an array to a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
const products = [
  "Underpants:6.99",
  "Socks:5.99",
  "T-shirt:14.99",
  "Trousers:31.99",
  "Shoes:23.99",
];

const total = products.reduce(
  (amount, current) => amount + parseFloat(current.replace(/[a-z-:]/gi, "")),
  0
);

console.log(total);
```